# Trouble passing a struct to a separate function in C

Tags: c, function, struct

I'm having trouble passing my struct to a new function. My current code opens a text file, saves the relevant information to the structure and prints the saved information. Now I'm trying to write a function that will ask the user to input a name and for the code to check all name fields in the struct and return inforamtion once found a result. The code works fine until I try pass the struct to the "searchDroneName" function. The main shows that I have saved the relevant information properly and I did the exact same for the "searchDroneName" function. But when I print out the saved information of the struct in the "searchDroneName" function it prints out a bunch of random numbers and weird characters.

I'm sure it's just my lack of understanding of functions and how to pass information but and help is appreciated, thanks.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DRONE_COUNT 10

typedef struct{

    int drone_number;
    char drone_name[20];
    int year_manufactured;
    double mass;
    double top_speed;
    double max_distance;
    double load_capacity;

} drone_info;


int searchDroneName(int no_of_drones){
    drone_info droneinfo[10];

    int i, found, numdrones;
    char namechoice[20];
    numdrones = no_of_drones;

    // Test Data    
        printf("Data:\n\n");
    for (i=0; i < numdrones; i++){
        printf("ID: %d Name: %s  Year: %d  Mass: %.2f  Top Speed: %.2f  Max Distance: %.2f Load Capacity: %.2f\n", 
        droneinfo[i].drone_number, droneinfo[i].drone_name, droneinfo[i].year_manufactured, droneinfo[i].mass, droneinfo[i].top_speed, droneinfo[i].max_distance, droneinfo[i].load_capacity);

    }


    printf("Input Drone Name: ");
    scanf("%19s", namechoice);
    found = 0;
    for (i=0; i < numdrones; ++i){
        printf("Drone Name: %s\n", droneinfo[i].drone_name);

        if (!strcmp(namechoice, droneinfo[i].drone_name)){

        printf("FOUND A MATCH");
        found = 1;
        }

    }

    if(found == 0){
        printf("No Matches Were Found!\n");

    }

    return 0;
}






int main(void) {
drone_info droneinfo[10];

int choice, droneID, yrman, i, no_of_drones;
float dronemass, dronemaxdist, dronetopspd, droneload;
char dronename[20];
i = 0;
    FILE* inputfile = fopen("drone.txt", "r");
    if(inputfile == NULL)
    {
        perror("ERROR! ");
        exit(-1);
    }

//GAY CODE BELLOW
    while(fscanf(inputfile, "%d %19s %d %f %f %f %f", &droneID, dronename, &yrman, &dronemass, &dronetopspd, &dronemaxdist, &droneload)==7){
        if(ferror(inputfile)){
            perror("An error occurred: ");

        }

        droneinfo[i].drone_number = droneID;
        strcpy(droneinfo[i].drone_name, dronename);
        droneinfo[i].year_manufactured = yrman;
        droneinfo[i].mass = dronemass;
        droneinfo[i].top_speed = dronetopspd;
        droneinfo[i].max_distance = dronemaxdist;
        droneinfo[i].load_capacity = droneload;

        i++;
    }
    no_of_drones = i;

    fclose(inputfile);

    printf("Data:\n\n");
    for (i=0; i < no_of_drones; i++){
        printf("ID: %d Name: %s  Year: %d  Mass: %.2f  Top Speed: %.2f  Max Distance: %.2f Load Capacity: %.2f\n", 
        droneinfo[i].drone_number, droneinfo[i].drone_name, droneinfo[i].year_manufactured, droneinfo[i].mass, droneinfo[i].top_speed, droneinfo[i].max_distance, droneinfo[i].load_capacity);

    }

//GAY CODE ABOVE




do{

  printf("Please select an option:\n\n");
  printf("1. Input/update drone information\n");
  printf("2. Search a drone\n");
  printf("3. Simulate a drone delivery scenario\n");
  printf("4. Display simulation results\n");
  printf("5. Save drone information\n");
  printf("6. Save all results\n");
  printf("7. Exit\n\n");

  scanf("%d", &choice);

  switch(choice)
  {
    case 1:
    //Input Drone Function

    break;

    case 2:
    //Search Drone function
    searchDroneName(no_of_drones);

    break;

    case 3:
    //Simulate Drone function

    break;

    case 4:
    //Display simulation results function

    break;

    case 5:
    //Save drone information function

    break;

    case 6:
    //Save all results function

    break;

    case 7:
    // Exit, Breaks loop

    break;

    default:
     printf("\nInvalid choice! Please enter a number inbetween 1 and 7!\n\n" );
    break;


  }


} while (choice != 7);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You need to read more about variables, variable life-time and variable-scope. You have two very different `droneinfo` variables, that are totally unrelated. To pass the `droneinfo` from the `main` function to the `searchDroneName` function, you need to actually pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Change

`int searchDroneName(int no_of_drones){
    drone_info droneinfo[10];`

to

`int searchDroneName(drone_info *droneinfo, int no_of_drones){`

and

```
    case 2:
    //Search Drone function
    searchDroneName(no_of_drones);
```

to

```
    case 2:
    //Search Drone function
    searchDroneName(droneinfo, no_of_drones);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. My understanding of functions and passing values is really bad. Appreciate it :D