# invalid type argument of '->' editing fields of a structure from a separate function

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct, structure

I'm having problems editing the fields of a structure from a seperate function, I'm trying to edit fields of my drone structure from the update droneinfofunction  .basically i get the same error for all the arrows (invalid type argument of  '->')

i'm sure this problem stems from my lack of understanding of pointers

any help would be greatly appreciated :)

here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define DRONE_COUNT 10

typedef struct{
//define struct info and variables
    int drone_number;
    char drone_name[20];
    int year_manufactured;
    double mass;
    double top_speed;
    double max_distance;
    double load_capacity;

} drone_info;

int updateDroneInfo(drone_info *droneinfo, int no_of_drones) {

    int searchID, numdrones, i, drYrMan;    
    double drMass, drTopSpeed, drMaxDist, drLoadCap;
    char drname[20];
    numdrones = no_of_drones;

    printf("what drone ID would you like to update?: ");
    scanf("%d", &searchID);
    printf("name: ");
    scanf("%s", drname);
    printf("year manufactured: ");
    scanf("%d", &drYrMan);
    printf("mass: ");
    scanf("%lf", &drMass);
    printf("top speed: ");
    scanf("%lf", &drTopSpeed);
    printf("max distance: ");
    scanf("%lf", &drMaxDist);
    printf("load capacity: ");
    scanf("%lf", &drLoadCap);

    droneinfo[searchID]->drone_number = searchID;
    droneinfo[searchID]->drone_name = drname;
    droneinfo[searchID]->year_manufactured = drYrMan;
    droneinfo[searchID]->mass = drMass;
    droneinfo[searchID]->top_speed = drTopSpeed;
    droneinfo[searchID]->max_distance = drMaxDist;
    droneinfo[searchID]->load_capacity = drLoadCap;



    for(i=0; i < numdrones; i++){




    }

return 0;

}



//drone search function
int searchDroneName(drone_info *droneinfo, int no_of_drones){


int i, found;
char namechoice[20];
printf("input drone name: ");
scanf("%s", namechoice);
found=0;


scanf("what drone would you like to search %s", namechoice);
for (i=0; i < no_of_drones; i++){
    if (!strcmp(namechoice, droneinfo[i].drone_name)) {

printf("found a match\n\nID: %d Name: %s  Year: %d  Mass: %.2f  Top Speed: %.2f  Max Distance: %.2f Load Capacity: %.2f\n", 
        droneinfo[i].drone_number, droneinfo[i].drone_name, droneinfo[i].year_manufactured, droneinfo[i].mass, droneinfo[i].top_speed, droneinfo[i].max_distance, droneinfo[i].load_capacity);


    found = 1;
    }

}

if(found == 0){
    printf("\nNo matches were found!\n");
}

return 0;

//make condition for all

}

int main(void)  {

drone_info droneinfo[10];   

int choice, droneID, yrman, i, no_of_drones;
double dronemass, dronemaxdist, dronetopspd, droneload;
char dronename[20];
i=0;

//open the drone.txt file where the drone info is stored
    FILE* inputfile = fopen("drone.txt", "r");
    if(inputfile == NULL)
    {
        perror("ERROR! ");
        exit(-1);
    }

//initialise the function that puts the struct in an array
    while(fscanf(inputfile, "%d %19s %d %lf %lf %lf %lf", &droneID, dronename, &yrman, &dronemass, &dronetopspd, &dronemaxdist, &droneload)==7){
        if(ferror(inputfile)){
            perror("An error occurred: ");

        }

        droneinfo[i].drone_number = droneID;
        strcpy(droneinfo[i].drone_name, dronename);
        droneinfo[i].year_manufactured = yrman;
        droneinfo[i].mass = dronemass;
        droneinfo[i].top_speed = dronetopspd;
        droneinfo[i].max_distance = dronemaxdist;
        droneinfo[i].load_capacity = droneload;

        i++;
    }

    no_of_drones = i;

    fclose(inputfile);

    //print the dtone info in an array
    printf("Data:\n\n");
    for (i=0; i < no_of_drones; i++){
        printf("ID: %d Name: %s  Year: %d  Mass: %.2f  Top Speed: %.2f  Max Distance: %.2f Load Capacity: %.2f\n", 
        droneinfo[i].drone_number, droneinfo[i].drone_name, droneinfo[i].year_manufactured, droneinfo[i].mass, droneinfo[i].top_speed, droneinfo[i].max_distance, droneinfo[i].load_capacity);

    }


do{
//program menu with appropriate menu items
  printf("Please select an option:\n\n");
  printf("1. Input/update drone information\n");
  printf("2. Search a drone\n");
  printf("3. Simulate a drone delivery scenario\n");
  printf("4. Display simulation results\n");
  printf("5. Save drone information\n");
  printf("6. Save all results\n");
  printf("7. Exit\n\n");

  scanf("%d", &choice);
    //switch for the 7 available menu cases
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1:
    //input drone function
    updateDroneInfo(droneinfo, no_of_drones);

    break;

    case 2:
    //search drone function
    searchDroneName(droneinfo, no_of_drones);

    break;



    case 3:
    //simulate drone function


    break;


    case 4:
    //display simulation results


    break;


    case 5:
    //save drone information


    break;



    case 6:
    //save all results function


    break;



    case 7:
    //exit/breaks the loop

    break;


    default:
      printf("Invalid Data Entered! please enter a number between 1 and 7\n\n");
    break;


    }
}   while(choice != 7);
return 0;

}
```

re

Comment: `droneinfo` is an array of `drone_info` *structure objects*, it's not an array of pointers. Therefore you need to use `.` like any other non-pointer structure.

Comment: `droneinfo[searchID]->drone_number` -> `droneinfo[searchID].drone_number`. Admittedly the error message from the compiler is not very good.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For future questions please try to reduce your code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem. You show tons of unrelated code. For compilation errors normally only very limited code is required.

Comment: You could also read directly into the structure members, as in `scanf("%d", &droneinfo[searchID].drone_number)`.

Comment: By the way (and totally unrelated to your problem), but is this some online challenge or assignment, or just an assignment for your local class? I wonder because [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62188025/440558) is working on the exact same problem. If it's a local class-assignment then perhaps you're class-mates and could help each other?

Answer (score 1):

```
droneinfo[searchID]
```

has the type `drone_info` and not `drone_info*`, so you use `.` instead of `->`.

Answer (score 1):

In statements like this:

```
droneinfo[searchID]->drone_number = searchID;
```

the expression `droneinfo[searchID]` is not a pointer. It has the type `drone_info` because the pointer `droneinfo` was already dereferenced by the subscript operator.

You have to write:

```
droneinfo[searchID].drone_number = searchID;
```

Also arrays do not have the assignment operator. You need to copy element elements from one array to another.

Instead of this statement:

```
droneinfo[searchID]->drone_name = drname;
```

you have to write using the standard string function `strcpy`:

```
$include <string.h>

//...

strcpy( droneinfo[searchID].drone_name, drname );
```

Comment: I've changed the program, and there's no errors, but now when i print out the data, its not saving the new drone information that gets input.

Comment: @jamisonralph You need to check that searchID is less than  no_of_drones.